# How do I pass a database connection into a method PHP

Tags: php, class, dbconnection

I have a class in PHP and one of the methods needs to access a database.How do I correctly pass a database connection variable to a method? Does it get passed as a parameter through the constructor or method? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: Yes it is possible, see my provided answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following updated answer. Tested and working.

```
  <?php

class SomeClass
{


    function setDb($servername, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        // Create the database connection and use this connection in your methods as $this->conn
        $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
        }
        echo "New successful connection to myDb  \n";
    }

    public function createTable()
    {
        // sql to create table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )";

        if ($this->conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New table created successfully \n";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $this->conn->error;
        }
    }
    public function normalInsertDb()
    {
        // sql to insert record using normal query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
        VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

        if ($this->conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record inserted successfully using normal sql statement \n";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $this->conn->error;
        }
    }
    public function preparedInsertDb()
    {
        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
        // set parameters and execute
        $firstname = "John";
        $lastname = "Doe";
        $email = "john@example.com";
        $stmt->execute();

        $firstname = "Mary";
        $lastname = "Moe";
        $email = "mary@example.com";
        $stmt->execute();

        $firstname = "Julie";
        $lastname = "Dooley";
        $email = "julie@example.com";
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "New records inserted successfully using PREPARED STATEMENTS \n";

        $stmt->close();
        $this->conn->close();
    }
}

$obj = new SomeClass();
$obj->setDb('localhost', 'homestead', 'secret', 'myDb'); //we assume the database myDb exists
$obj->createTable();
$obj->normalInsertDb();
$obj->preparedInsertDb();
```

My Result:

[image: my result]

Comment: Is this being run inside the method?

Comment: This absolutely doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Benni, sure, I have edited my answer and now it absolutely answers the question. It's Tested. Though it does not look like a very good approach though

Comment: @Alex, please test and confirm that it indeed works. Alternatively, you can pass the connection variables through a constructor. Let me know if you need more help with this.

Comment: @Lawrence Njenga I might be implementing this incorrectly but I am using prepared statements and I keep getting multiple errors starting with --Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given. All that I am passing is the connection variable, the type of data that will be passed in and the variable being passed in.

Comment: @Alex, sorry for late reply. Please see my updated answer with prepared statement preparedInsertDb() and normal sql queries normalInsertDb(). This should help. Please remember to mark my answer as correct if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the database connection is used only by one method of your object, there is nothing wrong about passing it as an argument to this method.

However, mostly this is not the case. So you would be better off, when you establish the db connection at an earlier stage (on top of your script) and then pass it as a constructor argument to all objects that will need it. Then, various objects can use the same connection for various methods and internal, private methods, too.

If you want to optimize further, wrap the connection into a dedicated class and use dependency injection to get it into the consumer objects.